# How do I transfer WebDriver to an imported test?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, python-unittest

Main module tests and imported ones must be executed in the same browser window. But something goes wrong:

***main_tests.py:***

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import import_test_set

class MainTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.url = "https://www.google.com/"
        s = Service("../chromedriver/chromedriver")
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_00_01_open_site(self):
        print('test_00_01_open_site')

        self.driver.get(self.url)
        self.assertIn("Google", self.driver.title)

    def test_00_02_imported_tests(self):
        print('test_00_02_imported_tests')

        imported_tests = import_test_set.ImportTestSet()
        imported_tests.set_driver(self.driver)
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(import_test_set)

        result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
        self.assertEqual(result.failures, [])
```

***import_test_set.py:***

```
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class ImportTestSet(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.i_wait = 5

    def set_driver(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_00_02_01_enter(self):
        print('test_00_02_01_enter')

        self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.i_wait)
        a_enter = self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Log in')
        a_enter.click()
        page_title = self.driver.title
        self.assertEqual(page_title, 'Google')
   
    def runTest(self):
        pass
```

The execution of the test method `test_00_02_01_enter`, implemented in the module `import_test_set.py`, produces the following error:

> File "C:\Users...\import_test_set.py", line 17, in test_00_02_01_enter self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.i_wait) AttributeError: 'ImportTestSet' object has no attribute 'driver'

I can’t understand why the driver is not passed to the imported test.
what is wrong in the code?

Comment: In the class `ImportTestSet` there isn't any attribute called `driver`. In the instruction`self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.i_wait)`,  `self` refers to an instance of the class `ImportTestSet`.

Comment: @frankfalse, I don't understand what the code should be to avoid the error. `driver` specified in the above method and it's called in `MainTests` class. Could you show the correct way?

Comment: I have added an answer. I hope it can be useful at least to pass the problem about `driver` attribute. When I wrote the previous comment I didn't understand your code. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem about the `driver` attribute try with the following modifications.
In the file **import_test_set.py**:

- add a class attribute `driver`
- the method `set_driver()` can be removed (stop to use it is enough)

```
class ImportTestSet(unittest.TestCase):

    # ----> add the following attribute driver
    driver = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.i_wait = 5

    # ----> remove or stop to use the method set_driver()
    #def set_driver(self, driver):
    #    self.driver = driver

    ...
```

In the file **main_tests.py** modify the method `test_00_02_imported_tests()` as following:

```
def test_00_02_imported_tests(self):
    print('test_00_02_imported_tests')

    # ---> remove the following instructions
    #imported_tests = import_test_set.ImportTestSet()
    #imported_tests.set_driver(self.driver)

    # ---> add the following instruction to set the attribute driver of ImportTestSet
    import_test_set.ImportTestSet.driver = self.driver

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(import_test_set)
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    self.assertEqual(result.failures, [])
```

Comment: how simple and effective it is, if you understand the subject. thanks